# Verify the Sequential Increment of a Property Common to Two Lists

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have following **two** lists.

**First list:**

List 1[0] {id=11111,date='01/01/2013',ProcessId='**100**'}
List 1[1] {id=11111,date='01/01/2013',ProcessId='**101**'}

**Second list:**

List 2[0] {id=11111,date='01/01/2013',ProcessId='**102**'}
List 2[1] {id=11111,date='01/01/2013',ProcessId='**103**'}

I need to check that second list '**List 2**' should start with next number for **ProcessId**.

Comment: post what did you try?

Comment: This question was asked by my friend, I don't know what it was for ? Sorry for not clarifying question. Thanks all anyway :) @mdisibio

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you composed your lists, and if they are truly Lists of anonymous object, but assuming they were constructed something like this:

```
var List1 = Enumerable.Range(100, 3).Select(i => new { id=1111, date="01/01/2013", ProcessId= i }).ToList();
var List2 = Enumerable.Range(103, 3).Select(i => new { id=1111, date="01/01/2013", ProcessId= i }).ToList();
```

Then you can verify that ProcessId of List2 is next in sequence like this:

```
bool list2StartsWithNextProcessId = List2.Min(o => o.ProcessId) == List1.Max(o => o.ProcessId) + 1;
```

Or more verbosely:

```
int list1Ender = List1.Max(o => o.ProcessId);
int list2Starter = List2.Min(o => o.ProcessId);
Console.WriteLine ("List1 EndsWith {0}. List2 StartsWith {1}, which is {2} next in sequence.", 
  list1Ender, 
  list2Starter, 
  list2Starter == list1Ender + 1 ? "" : "NOT");
```

Comment: List1.Max(o => o.ProcessId); is that line of code available?

Comment: @Lamourou If the Lists are composed of anonymous objects, as they appear to be, then yes. I ran this in LinqPad, but considered the construction of the lists irrelevent except to the OP.

Comment: @Lamourou I've added a sample list construction to the answer.

Comment: I tested it an it works very fine and like you said just with anonymous object.